# Function into function call javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a game Who Wants to be a Millionaire and I want to show the amount that a 
USER win either he finished the game or given a wrong answer. Here is the function of wrong answer (which end the game) and I dont know how to add/call amount code into it.

```
// Executes the proceedure of guessing incorrectly, losing the game.

self.wrongAnswer = function(elm) {
        $("#" + elm).slideUp('slow', function() {
            startSound('wrongsound', false);
            $("#" + elm).css('background', 'red').slideDown('slow', function() {
                $("#game").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $("#game-over").html('Game Over!')
                    $("#game-over").fadeIn('slow');
                    self.transitioning = false;
                });
            }); 
        });
    }


// Gets the money formatted string of the current won amount of money.

self.formatMoney = function() {
        return self.money().money(0, '.', ',');
    }
};
```

Comment: For one, where do you want to insert the money? Something like `$('#game-over').html('Game Over!<br \>You Would've Won ' + self.formatMoney')` would probably work.

Comment: Are you having some kind of problem with this code? Describe what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: We don't know either. Or are you implying that you want to call that `formatMoney` function and display its result next to the `Game Over!`?

Comment: Bro, I want to show Amount of money code in the wronganswer function. How can I add and where to add????

Comment: Bergi u right.....After Game Over title, the total amount of money user win should show. But I dont know how to add where to add????

Comment: Again, how do you want the "amount of money" to be displayed? Alongside "Game Over!"? Above it? Below it? In a separate dialog/overlay box?

Comment: Sterling W....I want to show below it...

Comment: Checking the code...

Comment: @Sterling W, not working Bro....game not started....

Comment: it just print the text instead of function....$("#game-over").html('Game Over!' + self.formatMoney)

Comment: There was an extra quote there by mistake. `$('#game-over').html('Game Over!<br \>You Would've Won ' + self.formatMoney)`

Comment: Now, it does not show anything....

Comment: It needs to be `$('#game-over').html('Game Over!<br \>You Would\'ve Won ' + self.formatMoney())` - notice the function parenthesis `()` and the cancellation of that added quote in would've `\'`

Comment: @OwenAyres: Check your quotes in `Would've` :P

Comment: @RocketHazmat Lol, thanks!

Comment: @Owen Ayres, thanks Bro...

Answer (score 1):

Final solution from OPs comments: -

> Just add the correct function call in the place you'd like it to appear.

```
$('#game-over').html("Game Over!<br \>You would've won " + self.formatMoney());
```